# How do I trigger my Google App script after I open a new tab?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

- **Context**

I am using Google Sheets as a database to store some stock price data. I have created a list of formulas that automatically populate cells on edit. What I am trying to do is to copy these formulas when I open a new tab for a new stock/company. Below is the code in app script I have created:

```
function setUpTrigger(){
 ScriptApp.NewTrigger('copyRowswithSetValues')
 }

function copyRowswithSetValues() {
 // Define the spreadsheet and sheet that we will get the data from. I want to trigger this when I insert a new tab. 
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 let sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Softcat');

 // Get the source range from the source sheet. It will get data from the range that has data
 let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
 let sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues();

 // Insert data into row when we open a new tab. From the first column 
 let rowCount = sourceValues.length;
 let columnCount = sourceValues[0].length; 

 // Where the data will be copied into
 let targetSheet = ss.insertSheet();
 let targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(1, 1, rowCount, columnCount);

 targetRange.setValues(sourceValues); 

  
 }//End of function
```

I was able to use the edit->current project's triggers to set-up the OnChange trigger.

- **Problem**

Whenever run this code, via the OnChange trigger, it repeatedly opens up a new tab and copies data from the source sheet to the new sheets. What I want is for the action to trigger **WHEN** I open a new tab. I suspect the issue I am having is the trigger and the `targetSheet` variable definition. But I'm not quite sure how exactly to achieve this.

*** UPDATE

```
function copyRowswithSetValues(e) {
  // Define the spreadsheet and sheet that we will get the data from. I want to trigger this when I insert a new tab. 
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Softcat');
  
  // Get the source range from the source sheet. It will get data from the range that has data
  let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
  let sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues();
  
  // Where the data will go (first row and column)
  let rowCount = sourceValues.length;
  let columnCount = sourceValues[0].length; 
  
  // Where the data will be copied into. Want it to trigger when I open a new tab
  let targetSheet = ss.INSERT_GRID;
  // Which row I want the data to be copied into, the column, number of rows and columns
  let targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(1, 1, rowCount, columnCount);
  
  targetRange.setValues(sourceValues); 
  
      
}//End of function
```

I am getting the error:

```
Error   
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of undefined
```

This I presume is because appscript can't find the range.

**Problem_2**

Do I remove the latter part (the target range variable)? I tried that but it did not succeed. Any suggestions?

*** Update 3

I was able to work something. This is what I got so far:

```
function Opennewtabandsave() {
// Within spreadsheet 
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
// Where the data is coming from
let sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Softcat');
 // Get data range from the source sheet
let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getDataRange();

// If we open a new sheet (as an event)
if(ss.insertSheet('New Stock')){
 // Create a variable for the new sheet
 let targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('New Stock');
 // Copy and paste source sheet to new opened sheet 
    sourceRange.copyTo(targetSheet.getRange(1,1));
    }
  }
```

So this works. Whenever I open a new tab, it creates the name and copies and pastes the data. Though the issue is that every time I open a new tab, it moves the tab to the position itself as the second tab. For example, If I open it after the 9th tab, this 'New Stock' tab will open in the second position.

Also, everytime I do something to the spreadsheet, new tabs open up. If I delete one it opens a new tab. I'm sure the On_grid feature works here but still have not seen anything to suggest how it's used in the code.

**Problem 3**

How can I get the new tab to open at the right position - to the right of the tab I opened it from?

**Problem 4**
How can I get the onChange trigger to only happen when I open a new tab and ignore all other actions?

Comment: You can generate a trigger with an onChange trigger of type 'INSERT_GRID' the problem  is that the event object does not provide a reference to the new sheet and the active sheet appears to remain that same as it was before the event.  I guess they did it this way so that you can't change the expected functionality of the insert new sheet operation for another user.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the active sheet does not change. That's a shame. Thanks for the response, much appreciated.

Comment: What is this `let targetSheet = ss.INSERT_GRID;` supposed to do? It makes no sense.

Comment: Yeah, so that's the thing, it's supposed to be the function to create the new spreadsheet tab. But I'm not sure exactly how to use it.

Comment: Well as I said before triggering this function with a onChange trigger is possible but the problem of passing the new sheet name to the function is a problem because the triggers event object does not contain a link to the tab or sheet.  So determination of sheet name is current impossible.  So to be clear I think what your asking for is impossible.

Comment: Ahh okay, yeah I remember. Do you think then it's possible if I create a new tab, wait for me to name it and then copy the data via appscript?

Comment: Yes I think that might work you could also use the script to do the same thing or at least part of it

Comment: Nice, thanks, will have a go tonight. Thanks for your help mate!

Comment: So sorry about the delay. I was busy trying to figure out how to do this. Well, I got it working, but some issues have popped up. Would appreciate some help again if possible. See above for an update.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I was able to do it - created a custom menu and select it every time I need a new spreadsheet that copies and pastes the source sheet as a template. Google Community helped with this. But so did you so thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [generate a trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) with an [onChange trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change) of type `INSERT_GRID` the problem is that the event object does not provide a reference to the new sheet and the active sheet appears to remain that same as it was before the event. I guess they did it this way so that you can't change the expected functionality of the insert new sheet operation for another user.

You say:

> Whenever run this code, via the OnChange trigger, it repeatedly opens up a new tab and copies data from the source sheet to the new sheets. What I want is for the action to trigger WHEN I open a new tab. I suspect the issue I am having is the trigger and the targetSheet variable definition. But I'm not quite sure how exactly to achieve this.

So you need to have an if statement with something like:

```
if(e.changeType=='INSERT_GRID') {
  //put rest of your code in here
}
```

you say:

> Do I remove the latter part (the target range variable)? I tried that but it did not succeed. Any suggestions?

I don't know what you mean?

you say:

> So this works. Whenever I open a new tab, it creates the name and copies and pastes the data. Though the issue is that every time I open a new tab, it moves the tab to the position itself as the second tab. For example, If I open it after the 9th tab, this 'New Stock' tab will open in the second position.

Also, everytime I do something to the spreadsheet, new tabs open up. If I delete one it opens a new tab. I'm sure the On_grid feature works here but still have not seen anything to suggest how it's used in the code.

I believe that you can control the position where you insert the new sheet but since the on change doesn't provide range you can't determine current sheet so that may not be something you can fix. The addition of utilizing the changeType should help with the second part

you ask:

> How can I get the new tab to open at the right position - to the right of the tab I opened it from?

I don't think you can with onChange event

you ask:

> How can I get the onChange trigger to only happen when I open a new tab and ignore all other actions?

The if statement already discussed should help with that.  If not there are not many other options since the onChange does not provide much info in the event object.

Comment: Thanks for this. So I am a little confused in writing this code out. I went through the docs but am unsure how exactly to create the trigger in appscript. This is what I got 
`function setUpTrigger(){
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('function').forSpreadsheet('spreadsheet id').onChange().create(); 
}`

Where exactly do I put the INSERT_GRID? I tried inputting it in the onChange but it failed to execute.

Comment: your function name cannot be `function` because function is a reserved word.  But the function is not going to contain a reference to you new sheet and `INSERT_GRID` is a type of change that it detects and it's part of the event object so you need to deal with that  in the trigger function code not in the trigger creation.

Comment: Apologies, the function was a dummy word. The actual script contains the function to copy and paste to a new sheet. I should have made that clearer, apologies.

Comment: I posted an update above with the changes. Would appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for this, the onChange trigger is a bit troublesome, it does not offer the other features I need. But will use this as an alternative should the above fail. Thanks for this! Now onto the other one (the dates). Been racking my head to figure these out. Will get to the others. Thanks man!